# How to search github for commits that include a file type with out another

Tags: github, advanced-search

What I am trying to do is find all/any commit in our repository that contains changes to a css file but that contains no changes to a sass file.

**End Goal:** standardizing all of our css

**Problem:** We are in the process of implementing coding standards to our moderately new startup and I have been given this task.  We compile our sass to css, but I have recently found out that over time some of the css files have been modified directly, so compiling the corresponding sass file would inevitably cause things to break. So we can't batch recompile all of our sass.

Comment: github won't help you. Clone two local copies, "A" and "B".  On one local copy ("A"), compile your SASS.  Then, compare all generated CSS files in "A" to those checked out in "B".  `find` and `diff` are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

A jenkins job could do this.

Run `git diff --name-only  HEAD^..` and that gives you the file list. If it contains a line with css and none with sass, then mark the build as failed.